# batch ftp windows server

Tags: windows, batch, línea-de-comandos

buenas tardes.
Necesito de su ayuda referente a un archivo batch que ejecuto sin problemas en windows 10, pero al implementarlo en windows server 2016 no funciona un 100%.

La funcionalidad es la siguiente, me conecto a un servidor ftp y descargo lo que tiene el ftp en una carpeta local del equipo con windows server pero lo raro es que no me trae la totalidad de archivos que existen en el ftp.

En el ftp tengo 10, solo me descarga 6 con el batch, procedimiento que funciona sin problemas en windows 10.

Adjunto el codigo que funciona en windows 10 :

```
open (ip ftp) 
usuario ftp 
password ftp 
lcd "ruta del disco local donde almaceno los archivos" 
mget * 
bye
```

Funciona son problemas en windows 10, pero solo me trae 6 de 10 archivos en windows server.

Los archivos sin todos excel(xlsx), todos iguales la misma extensión.

Sera algun parametro que me falta? otro comando a utilizar?

Favor de su ayuda.
Gracias.

Comment: un `list` ve los archivos?

Comment: Cuando corres esta secuencia manualmente en el WinServer, qué sale en consola?

Comment: si los ve, pero me sirvió tu dato estimado...logre darme cuenta que en el ftp hay archivos con tilde en su nombre y justo son los que no logra copiar a mi ruta local.

Comment: Como puedo tomar esos archivos con tilde en el procedimiento batch?...los archivos que no copia dice " 550 file no found"

Comment: el script está en UTF-8 ? en powershell hay un par de comandos para cambiar los locale `Get-WinSystemLocale` / `Set-WinSystemLocale` (no debería dar problemas pero vale la pena intentar) sino probar con otro cliente ftp

Answer (score 0):

Prueba añadiendo

```
OPTS UTF8 ON
```

antes del `mget` para que trabaje correctamente con nombres con caracteres especiales.

Comment: sigue omitiendo me esos archivos que llevan tilde en su nombre :( Gracias de todas formas amigo